# logging into corporate websites etc

Tags: networking, internet

I spend a lot of time using wireless provided by coffee shops, hospitals, etc, as a guest.     Typically these websites don't require a password but you have to accept the terms and conditions or click on something to get to the net.     It appears that windows, macs, iphones,  etc, jump to a welcome screen after connecting to one of these websites.    From the welcome screen you can accept terms, etc., and proceed to the web.    Same thing with coffee shops.     For some reason my system doesn't take me to any of these welcome websites.    When I ping the outside world I'm told I have a filtered connection.   The only way I get around this problem is to figure out the URL of the welcome screen and type it in.

So the question is:   is there something in my network settings that prevents my system from jumping automatically to the welcome screens?   Or is this just a linux limtation?    Do other people have this problem?  Thanks for any advice.    I apologize that it's a pretty amorphous question.

Comment: Which web browser are you using? Has Javascript been disabled or blocked? Are you using an adblocker?

Comment: Have you opened a web browser and tried to navigate to, say, a non-HTTPS website so that you get redirected into the gateway for that form?

Comment: Try `http://example.com` because they don't set HSTS headers

Answer (score 0):

You can access this "login" site almost always by typing in the gateway address into your webbrowser.

Open Terminal -> ifconfig.
Then open the Web-Browser and Type in the Gateway address und it should open the "login page"

Comment: Please don't start your answer with "I have this problem too..." It makes me think you are not trying to provide a solution, but saying "me too."

Comment: This doesn't always work, since the gateway IP address is not always the actual gateway you have to pass through

Comment: For me it always worked but yes you are technically right